# MSWord macro: search and highlight formatted text patterns

Tags: ms-word, vba, vbscript

I'm trying to write a MSWord macro that will find, and then highlight (in yellow), certain kinds of text strings in a MSWord file.

For example:

1) An italicized comma, followed by whitespace, and then a non-italicized text. Thus, for example:

> The *second* comma in this sentence, which is *italicized,* should be highlighted by the desired macro. *But the comma in this sentence should not be highlighted, because the entire sentence is in italics.*

2) A bolded character (of any kind, even whitespace), both preceded and followed by non-bolded characters. Thus, for example:

> This sentence ends in a bolded punctuation mark**.** That first period should be highlighted.

I know that first period might look normal, but it's not. It's bold. 

3) Any word that is in SmallCaps, and is >4 letters long, but is not capitalized. I don't know how to do smallcaps in markdown... but imagine for a moment that the following text is in smallcaps in MSWord:

> Imagine All of This Is in Small Caps. . .  the Word "under" Should Be Highlighted Because It Is More Than Four Characters Long but is not Capitalized

Does anyone know whether this is possible? I know it's quite easy to find text-patterns using regular expressions, but adding changes in formatting to those patterns seems to be tricky.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/07/14/how-can-i-search-for-and-reformat-highlighted-text-in-a-word-document.aspx How Can I Search For (and Reformat) Highlighted Text in a Word Document.

Comment: Thanks, but that would seem to be dealing with a slightly different scenario relating to finding highlighted text. My search patterns are a little bit more complicated.

Comment: http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/dsmyth/archive/2006/09/09/Regular-expressions-with-Word.aspx

http://www2.hawaii.edu/~chenx/reading/VBA/vb_regexp.html

Comment: Thanks again for your help. My problem, though, is that regular expressions don't seem to allow for pattern-matching that includes formatting. For example: There is no way, as far as I can tell, to write a regular expression that finds every word whose first character is both capitalized and bolded but the rest of the word is lowercase and non-bold.

Comment: @MarcusChan, thanks. My problem is a bit different than that he one you linked to, I think. I need a way to identify a pattern of text that is identified by a <i>change</i> in formatting. Thus, to provide another example: I would need to find a way to highlight an italicized vowel, followed by a non-italicized consonant. E.g., Th<i>i</i>s i<i>s</i> an <i>e</i>xamp<i>l</i>e. Only "is" and "ex" should match.

Comment: Oh, I was just trying to solve the formatting-based macro issue. I can't use regex to save my life, but I figured I might help someone write a proper script.

Comment: Still looking for a good answer for this problem. Would love any recommendations/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

run cmd,

```
cscript //Nologo regexp02.vbs
```

regexp02.vbs:

```
Dim objRegExp    : Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.Global = True

Dim input 
input="Imagine All of This Is in Small Caps. . . the Word under Should Be Highlighted Because It Is More Than Four Characters Long but is not Capitalized"

WScript.Echo input

WScript.Echo 

Dim Pattern1 : Pattern1 = "\b[a-z]{5,}\s"
WScript.Echo "Pattern1 : " & Pattern1
WScript.Echo 

objRegExp.Pattern = Pattern1

Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(input)

For i=0 To objMatches.Count-1
Set objMatch = objMatches.Item(i)
WScript.Echo objMatch.Value
Next

WScript.Echo 

Dim Pattern2 : Pattern2 = "\b[A-Z]([a-z]{4,})\s"
WScript.Echo "Pattern2 : " & Pattern2
WScript.Echo 

objRegExp.Pattern = Pattern2

Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(input)

For i=0 To objMatches.Count-1
    Set objMatch = objMatches.Item(i)
    WScript.Echo objMatch.Value

    WScript.Echo Left(objMatch.Value, 1)

'TODO test bold sumbol Left(objMatch.Value, 1)
'
'   TODO Highlight Code
'

Next
```

Output:

```
Imagine All of This Is in Small Caps. . . the Word under Should Be Highlighted Because It Is More Than Four Characters Long but is not Capitalized

Pattern1 : \b[a-z]{5,}\s

under

Pattern2 : \b[A-Z]([a-z]{4,})\s

Imagine
I
Small
S
Should
S
Highlighted
H
Because
B
Characters
C
```

Regex at VBA:

Open reference

[image: Open reference]

Select COM-server Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

[image: Select COM server]

VBA code:

```
Dim objRegExp As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

objRegExp.IgnoreCase = False
objRegExp.Global = True 

objRegExp.Pattern = Pattern1
```

Record macro

[image: Record macro]

Press Ctrl+F, open search dialog

[image: open search dialog]

select font property

[image: select font property]

select font style

[image: select font style]

Press Find Next

[image: Press Find Next]

Stop macro record, open VBA editor

[image: Stop macro record, open VBA editor]

Edit macro SearchItalic

[image: Edit macro SearchItalic]

Run macro SearchItalic

[image: Run macro SearchItalic]

Search italic text:

```
Sub SearchItalic()

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Italic = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm still having trouble with using regexes in conjunction with formatting characteristics. I need a way to select and highlight the first two examples that I provided in my initial post (italicized comma, bolded period). Any thoughts on how that might be possible?

Comment: Add Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 at VBA. Run macros record, edit autocode Alt+F11.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm still unclear as to whether Regular Expressions alone can solve the problem where I'm looking for patterns that involve *changes* in formatting. See my examples (1) and (2) in my original post for what I mean.

Comment: Regular Expressions - query text only. Use font object and search to change and find text style.

Comment: @STTR: I appreciate your will to help amitrus. But some steps can also be explained just by simple text like "Go to » Menu 1 » click Button 2". Anyway, this is a monster picture post.

Comment: @nixda I agree with you. Only one problem.) I do not know English)).

Comment: @nixda, thanks for your help. I'm still struggling, though with this problem. It seems that maybe I need to do some sort of mix of regexes and font-object search. Does anybody have a sense of how I could use those two tools together to do what I'm trying to do (see example (1) from the original post).

Comment: `input = "An italicized comma, followed by whitespace, and then a non-italicized text."`Example 1 - `Pattern3 = ",\s(.*?)\."` Return `, followed by whitespace, and then a non-italicized text.`

Comment: @STTR, thank you and I appreciate your persistence. But I don't think that would do the trick either. The "input" you have there has been stripped of all formatting (most importantly, the italicization of the first comma). It therefore does not represent the problem I'm trying to solve. Thanks for your help.